# Should I remove unused bits out of Web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

My current WebMatrix web site is very basic - it simply shows mostly static context, photos, and contains a few links. Many things are referenced in Web.config that I don't use in this site, such as support for SqlServerCe. Should I remove those things references, for performance purposes, or does it not matter to leave them in? I don't think I'm using the OAuth stuff, either (not deliberately, anyway), and I don't know about "WebGrease," etc.

I also wonder about removing StarterSite.sdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete almost everything from it. Mine looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Your assemblies can differ or miss.

Comment: Okay, I can, that's good, but does it help anything? Is there a performance benefit, or is this just a "cleanup"?

Comment: I believe that the overhead is not significant. However, these assemblies are probably added for some reason. In my case there was some pre-made C# code using OAuth etc. If you delete these source files also, I believe you can gain some performance benefit.